# Composing Applicatives

Tags: haskell, applicative, function-composition

I'm reading through Chapter 25 (Composing Types) of the [haskellbook](http://haskellbook.com/), and wish to understand applicative composition more completely

The author provides a type to embody type composition:

```
newtype Compose f g a =
  Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and supplies the functor instance for this type:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) =>
  Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) =
      Compose $ (fmap . fmap) f fga
```

But the Applicative instance is left as an exercise to the reader:

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) =>
  Applicative (Compose f g) where
    -- pure :: a -> Compose f g a
    pure = Compose . pure . pure
    -- (<*>) :: Compose f g (a -> b)
    --       -> Compose f g a
    --       -> Compose f g b
    Compose fgf <*> Compose fgx = undefined
```

I can cheat and look the answer up online... The source for [Data.Functor.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/src/Data-Functor-Compose.html#line-86) provides the applicative instance definition:

```
Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)
```

but I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here. According to type signatures, both `f` and `x` are wrapped up in two layers of applicative structure. The road block I seem to be hitting though is understanding what's going on with this bit: `(<*>) <$> f`. I will probably have follow up questions, but they probably depend on how that expression is evaluated. Is it saying "fmap `<*>` over f" or "apply `<$>` to f"?

Please help to arrive at an intuitive understanding of what's happening here.

Thanks! :)

Comment: `Compose fgh <*> Compose fgx = Compose ((<*>) <$> fgh <*> fgx) = Compose (liftA2 (<*>) fgh fgx)` and `liftA2 (<*>) fgh fgx ::~ f {gh <*> gx} :: f (g {h x})` (pseudocode, reading `{ }` as "type of").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the expression `a <$> b <*> c`. It means take the function `a`, and map it over the functor `b`, which will yield a new functor, and then map that new functor over the functor `c`.

First, imagine that `a` is `(\x y -> x + y)`, `b` is `Just 3`, and `c` is `Just 5`. `a <$> b` then evaluates to `Just (\y -> 3 + y)`, and `a <$> b <*> c` then evaluates to `Just 8`.

(If what's before here doesn't make sense, then you should try to understand single layers of applicatives further before you try to understand multiple layers of them.)

Similarly, in your case, `a` is `(<*>)`, `b` is `f`, and `c` is `x`. If you were to choose suitable values for `f` and `x`, you'd see that they can be easily evaluated as well (though be sure to keep your layers distinct; the `(<*>)` in your case belongs to the inner Applicative, whereas the `<$>` and `<*>` belong to the outer one).

Comment: This helped me a great deal to see a concrete example evaluated down:
Compose [Just (+1)] <*> Compose [Just 5] // 
Compose (<*>) <$> [Just (+1)] <*> [Just 5] // 
Compose [(<*>) (Just (+1))] <*> [Just 5] // 
Compose [Just (+1) <*> Just 5]  //
Compose [Just 6] //
```
I'm not sure why I over-complicated things :shrug:
Thanks Joseph!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `<*>`, you can define `liftA2`.

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative (..))

newtype Compose f g a = Compose
  { getCompose :: f (g a) }
  deriving Functor

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
  pure a = Compose (pure (pure a))
  -- liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b -> Compose f g c
  liftA2 f (Compose fga) (Compose fgb) = Compose _1
```

We have `fga :: f (g a)` and `fgb :: f (g b)` and we need `_1 :: f (g c)`. Since `f` is applicative, we can combine those two values using `liftA2`:

```
  liftA2 f (Compose fga) (Compose fgb) = Compose (liftA2 _2 fga fgb)
```

Now we need

```
_2 :: g a -> g b -> g c
```

Since `g` is also applicative, we can use its `liftA2` as well:

```
  liftA2 f (Compose fga) (Compose fgb) = Compose (liftA2 (liftA2 f) fga fgb)
```

This pattern of lifting `liftA2` applications is useful for other things too. Generally speaking,

```
liftA2 . liftA2 :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) => (a -> b -> c) -> f (g a) -> f (g b) -> f (g c)

liftA2 . liftA2 . liftA2
  :: (Applicative f, Applicative g, Applicative h)
  => (a -> b -> c) -> f (g (h a)) -> f (g (h b)) -> f (g (h c))
```

Comment: (... and `a <*> b === liftA2 id a b`.)